# Ruby on Rails log lines start with "I" or "W"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Noticed that all the lines in Rails log (`production.log` for example) start with either capital "I" or capital "W". For example

```
I, [2017-04-04T15:40:40.409423 #15879]  INFO -- : [8dd4dd50-2dba-466e-91c3-13e83333db78] Completed 302 Found in 96ms (ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
I, [2017-04-04T15:40:40.448567 #15866]  INFO -- : [e80b7bcc-92be-465a-a9b1-1f39222238cf] Started GET "/bla" for ip at 2017-04-05 15:40:40 +0200
I, [2017-04-04T15:40:40.454994 #15866]  INFO -- : [e80b7bcc-92be-465a-a9b1-1f39123138cf] Processing by blaController#index as HTML
```

Found no explanation for why is it like this and what's the purpose.

Comment: info, warning, error -)) and there is nothing to do with nginx (also with rails) it is a feature of ruby's Logger class https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html

Comment: oh, it is this simple :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's the standard [Logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) [Format](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Format) with [`SeverityID`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger/Severity.html) as the first value :

```
Log format:

SeverityID, [DateTime #pid] SeverityLabel -- ProgName: message

Log sample:

I, [1999-03-03T02:34:24.895701 #19074]  INFO -- Main: info.
```